# fetching data from JSON array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

From below **JSON** I want to retrieve all images from `imagePath` array. If I try to retrieve single image, it is being fetched smoothly. But the difficulty is arising while fetching `imagePath` array. Help me with the issue. 
Thanks

1). JSON

```
  [{
   "senderName": "ABC",
   "text": "Enjoy",
   "imagePath": [
       "../img/jellyfish.jpg",
       "../img/cat.jpg",
       "../img/fatmice.jpg",
       "../img/duck.jpg",
       "../img/d.jpg"],
    "senderImage": "../img/abc.jpg"
  }, {
    "senderName": "XYZ",
    "text": "Enjoy",
    "imagePath": [
        "../img/jellyfish.jpg",
        "../img/cat.jpg",
        "../img/d.jpg"],
    "senderImage": "../img/abc.jpg"
  }, {
    "senderName": "PQR",
    "text": "Enjoy",
    "imagePath": [
        "../img/jellyfish.jpg",
        "../img/cat.jpg",
        "../img/d.jpg"],
    "senderImage": "../img/abc.jpg"
  }]
```

2). that is the controller.js file for the above JSON

```
     http.get('../js/postData.json')
      .success(function (response) {
         $scope.data = response;
        console.log(response);        
      }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
       })
```

3). And the corresponding HTML file is :

```
   <div class="list" ng-repeat="user in data">
     <a class="item item-avatar">
     <img ng-src="{{user.senderImage}}" align="left">
     <h4 align="left">
         {{user.senderName}}
     </h4>
   </a>
   <p>
     {{user.text}}
    </p>
   <div>
    <img ng-src="{{user.imagePath}}">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: imagePath is an array. so iterate each elements <div ng-repeat="img in user.imagePath" >
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
   </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="user in data">
     <a class="item item-avatar">
     <img ng-src="{{user.senderImage}}" align="left">
     <h4 align="left">
         {{user.senderName}}
     </h4>
   </a>
   <p>
     {{user.text}}
    </p>
   <div>
    <img ng-src="{{image}}" ng-repeat="image in user.imagePath">
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to load all images:

```
 <img ng-repeat="imagePath in user.imagePath" ng-src="{{imagePath }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use a nested loop

```
<img ng-repeat="singleImg in user.imagePath" ng-src="{{singleImg}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="user in data">
 <a class="item item-avatar">
 <img ng-src="{{user.senderImage}}" align="left">
 <h4 align="left">
     {{user.senderName}}
 </h4>
 </a>
 <p>
 {{user.text}}
</p>
<div>
    <!--Changes are made here-->
    <div ng-repeat="path in user.imagePath">
      <img ng-src="{{path}}">
    </div>
    <!--Changes ends here-->
 </div>
 </div>
```